# how to resolve this pytest error? -process while deploy docker app to azure

Tags: azure, docker, pytest

```
name: Pytest
      continue-on-error: false
      run: |
        mkdir testresults
        pip install pytest && pytest Tests/unit_tests --junitxml=./testresults/test-results.xml && pip install pycmd && py.cleanup Tests/

'''


the following error occurs from the above code
```

ERROR Tests/unit_tests/test_views.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 0.16s ===============================
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

```
help me to understand and how to proceed further.
```

Comment: note: error while build and deploy python app to azure

Comment: Are you trying the [same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli) process?

Answer (score 0):

***Check below points to resolve Pytest error***:

Try install & import `Pytest` with command
`pip install pytest`.

Note: Make sure you have installed latest versions of `pip(22.3.1)` & `Python(3.11)`.

[Check Pytest import errors here](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=abe4b84c46d9e8c9JmltdHM9MTY3MTkyNjQwMCZpZ3VpZD0xMjVhNTgzNy01ZWY1LTZlZDMtMzA0YS00YTM4NWZhNzZmZTUmaW5zaWQ9NTQyNA&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=125a5837-5ef5-6ed3-304a-4a385fa76fe5&psq=how%20to%20resolve%20this%20pytest%20error&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmZpbnh0ZXIuY29tL2ZpeGVkLW1vZHVsZW5vdGZvdW5kZXJyb3Itbm8tbW9kdWxlLW5hbWVkLXB5dGVzdC8jOn46dGV4dD1PdGhlciUyMFNvbHV0aW9uJTIwSWRlYXMlMjAxJTIwVGhlJTIwTW9kdWxlTm90Rm91bmRFcnJvciUyMG1heSUyMGFwcGVhcixpbi1kZXB0aCUyMGd1aWRlJTIwb24lMjBpbnN0YWxsaW5nJTIwcHl0ZXN0JTIwaGVyZS4lMjBNb3JlJTIwaXRlbXM&ntb=1)

If the issue still persists, download & install `pytest` file in the local environment to have dependencies to configure pytests in Python Server.

[Pytest failures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/failures.html)

I tried [similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=django,windows,azure-portal,azure-cli-deploy,deploy-instructions-azportal,terminal-bash,deploy-instructions-zip-azcli#4---browse-to-the-app) deployment as per your requirement in my environment with a workaround, it worked as expected.

***apps.py:***

```py
from  django.apps  import  AppConfig
class  HelloAzureConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'xxxxxhello'
```

***Ran on Python Server Port:***

[image]

***Triggered and server***(`.Py`) ***is running after successful build in local:***

[image]

***Created an Azure Web app through portal and deployed successfully***:

[image]

*After deployment* ***https://< webapp >.azurewebsites.net***:

[image]